# Permission denied while connecting Amazon EC2 with GIT trought SSH

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2, bitbucket

I am using Amazon EC2 instance as dev server and I am trying to git clone my repository from bitbucket to amazon EC2 instance. What i like to do is to add post hook commit to bitbucket, so all changes committed to the repository automatically to reflect to my dev server.

I am connecting trough ssh to my Amazon EC2 instance, but when i try to git clone the repository i am getting following error:

```
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I found many solutions about this problem but none of them seems to work!

Here is what i have tried so far:

-created elastic ip and associate with my instance

-modified the security group  to allow inbound network traffic

-download the generated pem key from amazon and generate private and public key using puttygen

-uploaded the public key (id_rsa.pub) and pem key to my .ssh folder and changed the permissions to 600

-added the public key to bitbucket deployment keys

-added the public key to the authorized_keys file on amazon

-created a config file inside .ssh folder and added following lines inside:

```
Host bitbucket.org
Hostname bitbucket.org
User ubuntu
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/amzon_key.pem
```

-tried to git clone the repository as root user

I'm using putty on windows.

Answer (score 1):

*Solution by OP.*

What I did to make it work:

-deleted the config file from .ssh folder

-created new private and public keys using puttygen (dsa - 1024)

-added the public key to the bitbucket deployment keys

-added the public key to the amazon authorized_keys file in the .ssh folder

-uploaded the keys to the .ssh folder and set permissions to 600

-added bitbucket.org to the list  of known_hosts file in the .ssh folder

Answer (score 0):

The key that we need to add here is the one that we have added in the bitbucket. So the server has permission to access the bitbucket and perform the git commands. So change the identity file name with the name that you have added. As in the Question, it is id_rsa.

```
Host bitbucket.org
Hostname bitbucket.org
User ubuntu
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

This is a suggestion. Because I don't have enough reputation to comment.